# Differences or proper way to format a typedef struct statement in C?

Tags: c

I've seen structs declared two different ways.

```
typedef struct _myStruct {
    ...
} myStruct;
```

and

```
typedef struct myStruct {
    ...
} myStruct;
```

Is there a reason for the leading underscore or is this just a stylistic thing? If there is not a difference, is one of these preferred over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former was used long ago, when some compiler(s) didn't allow the tag and the typedef to use the same identifier. The latter is currently preferred, and in fact, identifiers that start with an underscore are discouraged.

Comment: I have seen some people use `typedef struct tMyType{ ... } MyType; `, the "t" presumably standing for "tag". This way, you can both avoid using a leading underscore and still distinguish between the tag and the actual `typedef`'ed name, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

There are reasons not to use the leading underscore, notably that names starting with an underscore are basically reserved for use by the implementation.  The details are a little more nuanced than that, but it is easier to remember.

> ### ISO/IEC 9899:2011
>
> #### 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers
>
> 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers
>
> ¶1 Each header declares or defines all identifiers listed in its associated subclause, and optionally declares or defines identifiers listed in its associated future library directions subclause and identifiers which are always reserved either for any use or for use as file scope identifiers.
>
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.
> - All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.
> - …

Consequently, using the leading underscore is treading on thin ice.  Usually, you'll get away with.  However, sometimes you won't, and when you won't, you have no recourse because you've been treading outside the limits of the namespace that the standard allows you to use.

If the structure tag and the type name are the same, you don't have to guess which structure tag goes with which type name (alias).

Note that the Linux kernel coding standards reject typedefs for structures.  You'll have to decide whether you want to follow that rule.  Many systems do not follow it.

One other minor issue is that C++ performs the equivalent of `typedef struct MyStruct MyStruct;` automatically — after defining a `class` or `struct` (or `union`) with a tag name, you can use the tag name as a type name.  It isn't identical — you can do the `typedef` yourself and it compiles cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Completely stylistic. Just visually differentiates the "synthetic type" from the declared variable of that type.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do :-

```
typedef struct {
    ...
} myStruct;
```

Comment: except it would be 'myType'